# load-scripts.php loads incorrect file names

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using the theme Enfold (3.5.3) with WPML and some smaller plugins (deactivating doesn't help).

After activating Yoast SEO, I've noticed that the built-in Avia Layout Builder's spinner loads endlessly on the edit page screen. Furthermore, it breaks all following JavaScript, including Yoast SEO.

[image: spinner]

Two JS errors are being displayed in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toArray'
```

and

```
wp-auth-check.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
```

By looking at the *load-scripts.php* link inside the HTML source code, I see a couple of corrupted parameters:

```
.../wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,underscore,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,utils,backbone,pluploa&load%5B%5D=d,wp-a11y,jquery-ui-progressbar,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-button,jq&load%5B%5D=uery-ui-dialog&ver=4.6.1
```

There were two similar threads here on Stackexchange, but the solutions posted there did not help.

Comment: What were the solutions you tried?

Comment: Hello kolja, welcome to WPSE. Questions related to third party themes and plugins are off-topic here, so the best way forward would be for you to use the support resources offered by the developers of the third party products you're using. For more information on what kinds of questions are on topic, [take a look here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking).